# Narrow typing for short circuit `or`, when I have two possible cases

Tags: mypy, python-typing, type-annotation

I'm trying to annotate the following code.

The function designed to work when both `zone` and `zones` defined, or when `file` is defined (but not both):

```py
def get_file(zone: str, zones: dict[str, str]) -> pathlib.Path:
    pass

def connect(
        zone: str | None = None,
        zones: dict[str, str] | None = None,
        file: pathlib.Path | None = None,
) -> bool:
    file = file or get_file(zone, zones)
```

But it makes `mypy` angry -

```
1. Argument of type "str | None" cannot be assigned to parameter "zone" of type "str" in function "_get_vpn_file"
     Type "str | None" cannot be assigned to type "str"
       Type "None" cannot be assigned to type "str"
2. Argument of type "dict[str, str] | None" cannot be assigned to parameter "zones" of type "dict[str, str]" in function "_get_vpn_file"
     Type "dict[str, str] | None" cannot be assigned to type "dict[str, str]"
       Type "None" cannot be assigned to type "dict[str, str]"
```

Then I tried to make some aggressive type narrowing:

```py
def _check_params_are_ok(
    zone: str | None, zones: dict[str, str] | None, file: pathlib.Path | None,
) -> tuple[str, dict[str, str], None] | tuple[None, None, pathlib.Path]:
    if zone is not None and file is not None:
        raise ValueError("Pass `file` or `zone`, but not both.")

    if zone is not None and zones is None:
        raise ValueError("connect: Must define `zones` when `zone` is defined.")

    if zone is None and file is None:
        raise ValueError("connect: Must define `zone` or `file`.")

    assert file is not None or (zone is not None and zones is not None)

    # Type narrowing
    if zone is not None and zones is not None and file is None:
        return zone, zones, file
    if zone is None and zones is None and file is not None:
        return zone, zones, file

    raise NotImplementedError("This error from _check_params_ok shouldn't happen.")


def connect(
        zone: str | None = None,
        zones: dict[str, str] | None = None,
        file: pathlib.Path | None = None,
) -> bool:
    zone, zones, file = _check_params_are_ok(zone, zones, file)
    file = file or get_file(zone, zones)
```

And mypy still shows the same errors.

Mypy still shows the same errors even when adding very clear assertions:

```py
    zone, zones, file = _check_params_are_ok(zone, zones, file)
    if file is None:
        assert zone is not None and zones is not None
    file = file or get_file(zone, zones)
```

The best solution I found so far is to cast the types inline, but it effects the code readability and make the line hard to read:

```py
    file = file or get_file(cast(str, zone), cast(dict[str, str], zones))
```

Is there any good way to narrow the types?

Comment: Can't you have `str | None` and `dict... | None` in `get_file` ? That would fix your issue

Comment: But it shouldn't allow `None`s ^^"

Comment: to clarify, you're asking how to get the types working in the implementation, not the function signature?

Comment: Currently I get a mypy error. mypy thinks `zone`/`zones` can be `None`, even when `file` is falsy. That is obviously not the case. I want to make mypy understand it :)

Comment: If you are set on using the short circuit 'or' whatever you do has to be on the right-hand side of the 'or'. As an alternative to casting maybe a conditional expression: `file = file or (get_file(zone, zones) if zone is not None and zones is not None else None)`

Answer (score 3):

In your code when you do the — as you put it — *very clear assertions*, you can assign to `file` only in the body of the `if` statement:

```py
if file is None:
    assert zone is not None and zones is not None
    file = get_file(zone, zones)

# file is now a pathlib.Path object
assert file.is_file()  # this is now valid
```

Then you will be very explicit and `mypy` shouldn't complain anymore about this.

Comment: You can even drop the `assert file is not None`. Mypy is smart enough for that

Comment: @Wombatz, yes, this was just a demonstration that the OP can work further as if it is true. But thanks for the remark. I'll remove it to make it less confusing.

Comment: Thanks :) I've upvoted, but the question specifically asks about short circuit `or`.

Answer (score 3):

The [answer by Stefan Marinov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74305938/19770795) is correct. Assertions are useful for these situations.

I would just like to add for the sake of completeness that in such constructs, when you know that only *specific* combinations of call arguments are supposed to occur, it is advisable to define your overload call variants:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import overload

def get_file(zone: str, zones: dict[str, str]) -> Path:
    return NotImplemented

@overload
def connect(zone: str, zones: dict[str, str], file: None = None) -> bool:
    ...

@overload
def connect(zone: None, zones: None, file: Path) -> bool:
    ...

def connect(
    zone: str | None = None,
    zones: dict[str, str] | None = None,
    file: Path | None = None,
) -> bool:
    if file is None:
        assert zone is not None and zones is not None
        file = get_file(zone, zones)
    return NotImplemented
```

This allows type checkers (and by extension your IDE) to alert you to incorrect usage of `connect`. For example, these two calls will both cause `mypy` errors, when the overload signatures are defined properly:

```py
connect(None, None, None)
connect("abc", {"x": "y"}, Path("."))
```

---

Although, for what it's worth, I would suggest at least reconsidering, if this design is truly what you want. Calling a function as `connect(None, None, Path(...))` seems very unnatural to me. If this is indeed the way the function is supposed to be called, I would probably at least opt for making all arguments **keyword-only**, thus allowing more explicit and readable calls:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import overload

def get_file(zone: str, zones: dict[str, str]) -> Path:
    return NotImplemented

@overload
def connect(*, zone: str, zones: dict[str, str]) -> bool:
    ...

@overload
def connect(*, file: Path) -> bool:
    ...

def connect(
    *,
    zone: str | None = None,
    zones: dict[str, str] | None = None,
    file: Path | None = None,
) -> bool:
    if file is None:
        assert zone is not None and zones is not None
        file = get_file(zone, zones)
    return NotImplemented


connect(file=Path("."))
connect(zone="abc", zones={"x": "y"})
```

But this may just be subjective. You know better, what you need for your purposes.

**EDIT**: Just realized that the implementation has `None` defaults for all arguments, so calling it as I suggested was already possible. Still, I would argue that enforcing keyword-only would be more explicit and *"explicit is better than implicit"*.